# Can I safely clone an encrypted drive with dd without harming the data

Tags: windows, encryption, dd, veracrypt, copy

I have a windows hard drive encrypted, using veracrypt, with AES HMAC-SHA-512, but from which the password was lost.  Can I safely make a copy of this information bit by bit using something like dd?  If not, are there any tools I can use that will make a copy without harming the data, or the ability to decrypt the information once copied?  That is, will the data that is copied be usable?

Comment: Changing your question after you've received answers is inappropriate, as it invalidates the answers you've received. It can even make those answers wrong, and adversely affect the reputation of those who answered. If you now have a new or additional question, create a new post and ask it there; you can link back to this one if needed for reference.

Comment: How on earth could cloning harm data(encrypted or not)..(unless you messed up and didn't clone).   And asking if the data will be usable is another matter.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I safely make a copy of this information bit by bit using something like dd?

Encrypted data is still just data. It can be read and written and is not "live" or self-destructing in any way, and the disk itself doesn't even know the difference between encrypted and not.

Because you know the software used, ability to decrypt depends entirely on whether you have the key or not. VeraCrypt only uses your provided passphrase as the key – it does not use any of the drive's "physical" information (such as serial numbers) for this purpose, so the data will remain decryptable even if it's copied elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

*Although I can't speak on [what the question was asking prior to any edits](https://superuser.com/questions/1561572/can-i-safely-clone-an-encrypted-drive-with-dd-without-harming-the-data#comment2377429_1561572), I would hope to add an answer to what's being asked now, since it remains to be seen as being marked as answered:*

## Answer: Yes, yes you can.

Yes, you *can* safely copy the encrypted data, in it's "encrypted form" (sort of speak) so that when you decrypt and access it later from said copy, you will be able to retrieve, read, view, and modify the unencrypted, or more specifically decrypted, data in it's entirety and unharmed. It will be as if it were the actual drive with so long as there are no extraneous events that occur and under the presumption that you didn't mismatch some setting on `dd`.

The "exception" if you want to call it that, or possible 'harm' that can be done *per se*, would be if you change the type of medium you're using `dd` to copy to and if it happens to also be one containing the boot drive. That is to say, the data itself isn't harmed by the process of copying itself, but an unexpected route of access, for example through SATA instead of NVMe/M2 port, that *may or may not* cause an issue at boot, if by chance, 'usable' might've included a reference to being 'bootable' as well.

For instance, if copying an NVMe drive to a SDD drive with dd:

```
dd if=/dev/nvme0n1 of=/dev/sda
```

Most people would be fine. But, on the rare occasion that someone might've set their onboard sata controller as disabled in the  bios setting then they might think something is wrong with the copied data sd wasn't detecting the newly copied drive because they didn't realize that even though they've replicated the drive, they changed the interface that boots the drive . **Though it's not directly related to answer your question specifically, I just thought it was important to note above for anyone who finds themselves hitting an error.**

### Example from personal experience

From recent experience I can tell you that I have a laptop with a LUKS1 encrypted root partition and unencrypted boot partition (GRUB) on a 512GB NVMe drive. I used `dd` to make a copy of the entire disk, to a partition on a 4 TB USB external, specifically:

```
dd if=/dev/nvme0n1 of=/dev/sda2 bs=1M conv=noerror,sync status=progress
```

And as a result, here were the different use cases I experienced and can speak on from personal experience:

1. If I tried to boot from the UBS, I would fall into a GRUB rescue shell which required I change the `set` options for which hard disk partition was assigned as the root drive. (Hard disk partition because the USB external 4TB storage is an HDD-based external)
2. For a similar scenario but whereas the NVMe drive was 256 GB and was copied to another partition of the USB drive, when I `dd` copied it to a new NVMe drive that was twice the size, then from a live boot perspective it had issues recognizing the different partitions. However, after fixing some fstab settings and grub settings on boot, (basically the drive mapping) then I was able to boot from the copied data
3. As an additional safety measure, I copied the entire 512GB NVMe as an image backup (.img) instead of a direct, to-partition-bit-for-bit copy, in addition to partition image backups of each individual aside from one **.img** of the entire disk.

So in in all cases, the encrypted data was able to be decrypted once properly mounted or recognized on a kernel level. So long as no interruptions or hiccups occur, there is no reason to believe you would not be able to access the encrypted data later unless the encryption type heavily relied on identifiers of the disk itself.

## Additional Notes

- Extensive conversation regarding `dd`'s use as a command for backup (with
  arguments against its efficiency) can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/4906/using-dd-for-disk-cloning). Whereas a deeper technical look into `dd` as explained by a fellow user can be read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48973798/13824314).
- For a full tutorial on how to use `dd` to backup a drive or partition,
  you can check out the walkthrough [here](https://www.linux.com/topic/desktop/full-metal-backup-using-dd-command/) or see 6 different examples of using `dd` [here](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/dd-command-examples/)..
- One of the downsides to using `dd` for such a purpose though is its
  lack of efficiency since it copies the bits of blank space as well.
  There are a number of ways to speed up the process and though you'll
  find plenty in the link above, the one I found most helpful from
  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33485108/why-is-dd-with-the-direct-o-direct-flag-so-dramatically-faster) was to add the `oflag=direct` argument.
- According this [one comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/4906/using-dd-for-disk-cloning#comment750549_4912), one can more easily address the
  issue I experienced regarding booting from a restored copy of the
  partition by running `partprobe -s`

Though there are other commands out there that can do the same thing, but one that i found after the fact that I found to be faster and more informative (in terms of a status of how it's going to take or is taking) would be the command `pv` In case you're not familiar with using `pv` here's the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/pv.1.html).

#### Other *Maybe* Useful Links

- [When mounted or unmounted is needed/ideal for using dd](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/using-dd-on-mounted-and-unmounted-partitions-4175523410/)
- [How to Speed up the transfer read/write speed used by dd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/523037/how-would-i-speed-up-a-full-disk-dd)
- [Different ways to monitor the progress of dd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215505/how-do-you-monitor-the-progress-of-dd)

All the links provided above were links I had found and used to find self-assurance in the backup method of using `dd` for myself so I hope it can do the same for you or anyone else who stumbles upon this.

Answer (score -1):

#### I have a windows hard drive encrypted, using `Veracrypt`, but the password was lost.

If you have lost the password then there is no possibility to recover the data.

> with AES HMAC-SHA-512

This generates strong encryption making recovery even less likely.

> are there any tools I can use that will make a copy without harming the data

Yes, but it is pointless as you have lost the password.

> will the data that is copied be usable?

You have lost the password so you cannot decrypt it.

Without the password it doesn't matter where that data is located you cannot decrypt it.